# Accessing the pixels of an image

Tags: java, swing

Could someone show me here how to access all the pixels of an image in order to be able to build a histogram of that image ?

Comment: You need to specify the platform - J2ME, Android, AWT vs Swing, J2SE etc all have different image components

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( "image.gif" );
int[] samples = image.getData().getPixel( x, y, null );

// or the pixel converted to the default RGB color model:
int rgb = image.getRGB( x, y )
```

I think the `samples` you get from there are the RGB values, but you have to check that...

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) it has options to generate [Histograms](http://www.raditha.com/java/image/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code that might help - please test this (it seems to work for me, but you never know!).

This histograms aren't equalized or anything here, just literally counting up the pixel of a particular value in each band.

I believe the bands (you would need to check) are R,G,B + Alpha in that order.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SimpleImageReader {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // File f=new File(args[0]);
        File f=new File("C:\\1.jpg");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
        Raster r=img.getData();
        int levels=256;
        int bands=r.getNumBands();
        int histogram[][]=new int[bands][levels]; 

        for (int x=r.getMinX();x<r.getWidth();x++) {
            for (int y=r.getMinY();y<r.getHeight();y++) {
                for (int b=0;b<3;b++) {
                    int p=r.getSample(x, y, b);
                    histogram[b][p]++;
                }
            }
        }
      for (int b=0;b<histogram.length;b++) {
        System.out.println("Band:"+b);
        for (int i=0;i<histogram[b].length;i++) {
          System.out.println("\t"+i+"="+histogram[b][i]);
        }
       }
}
}
```